# How to automatically logout after register in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Now in my wordpress website after the user is registering is redirected to my account page (i use woocommerce).

I want hime to be logged out automatically after register.

Because I want to approve it first.

This is the code:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $nua = pw_new_user_approve();
    $status = $nua->get_user_status(get_current_user_id());
    if ($status === 'pending') {?>
        HERE IS THE FUNCTION TO LOGOUT AUTOMATICALLY!
        <?php

    }
}
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $nua = pw_new_user_approve();
    $status = $nua->get_user_status(get_current_user_id());
    if ($status === 'pending') {
    $redirect = 'sitepath'; 
wp_logout_url($redirect);       

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: it's not working... tryied with this too wp_logout_url(get_bloginfo('url'));  nothing :(

Comment: please check the condition if ($status === 'pending') { } right?

Comment: ` if ($status === 'pending') {?>
        <p>You must wait for account acctivation. Thank you!</p>
        <?php  
  wp_logout_url(get_bloginfo('url'));   
 }` the **<p>** is visible on my account page

Comment: please try this $url = get_bloginfo('url');
 $redircturl = wp_logout_url($url); 
 
 ?>
<a href="<?php echo $redircturl ?>"><img src="any path" id ="sa"></a>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("#sa").trigger("click");
  });
  
 </script>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $nua = pw_new_user_approve();
    $status = $nua->get_user_status(get_current_user_id());
    if ($status === 'pending') {
    wp_logout();
    }
}
```

Comment: the same, i can see the **<p>** but no log out :(

Comment: And you have tagged the if statement with <?php ?> ?

Comment: How about in your user table, shouldn't the status be numeric instead of words?

Comment: `if ($status === 'pending')` this is working fine, i just need a function to run the logout

Comment: Oh, okay. Then just try session_destroy();

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try to this

```
<?php echo wp_logout_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); ?>
```

Comment: this returns the link http://website/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=%2Fmy-account%2F&_wpnonce=2015095cc8